# Can't add script to a prefab

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine, scripting

I've been following a YouTube tutorial on coding, but I can't attach the script to the prefab as it keeps saying no monobehaviour or script class and file does not match.

I have renamed my script to MYPlayer and prefab to MYPlayer, but it still doesn't work. Any help is much appreciated.

Here's my code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class MYPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Controls controls;

    [SerializeField] private bool moveKeyHeld;

    private void Awake() => new Controls();

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        controls.Enable();

        controls.Player.Movement.started += OnMovement;
        controls.Player.Movement.canceled += OnMovement;

        controls.Player.Exit.performed += OnExit;

    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        controls.Disable();

        controls.Player.Movement.started -= OnMovement;
        controls.Player.Movement.canceled -= OnMovement;

        controls.Player.Movement.Exit.performed -= OnExit;
    }

    private void OnMovement(InputAction.CallbackContext ctx)
    {
        if (ctx.started)
        moveKeyHeld = true;
        else if (ctx.canceled)
        moveKeyHeld = false;
    }

    private void OnExit(InputAction.CallbackContext ctx)
    {
        Debug.Log("Exit");
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.postion += (Vector3)controls.Player.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        GameManager.instance.EndTurn();
    }
}
```

I followed the tutorial, but I can't attach the script, an error called "script class cannot be found" appears.

Answer (score 0):

This problems appears when the class name and the file name are different. Rename the MYPlayer class file to MYPlayer.cs and it should work.